# How does breaking zombies work?

Tags: dead-island

As far as I can tell, a zombie has both a yellow health bar and a red health bar. The yellow health bar indicates the amount of stamina a zombie has left; once exhausted by taking damage it collapses. The red health bar indicates the amount of health the zombie has left; once depleted, the zombie "breaks", or dies permanently.

Still, the way that depleting the red health bar works confuses me, and I want to make sure that I kill zombies as quickly as possible to keep my weapons in tip-top shape. Do I deal less health damage to a zombie while it still has stamina? Will aiming at the zombie's head inflict more health damage, even when it's knocked down? Do certain types of weapons inflict more health damage compared to stamina damage, regardless of their base damage (for example, if I have a firearm and a blunt weapon with the same attack value, will the firearm inflict more health damage)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Do I deal less health damage to a zombie while it still has stamina?

The inverse - I don't believe zombies take less damage when they have stamina, but if they are knocked down (either as a result of having no stamina or via throwing/ramming/etc.), they take more damage.

- Will aiming at the zombie's head inflict more health damage, even when it's knocked down?

Yes, and you will occasionally get a time slowdown when this happens.

- Do certain types of weapons inflict more health damage compared to stamina damage, regardless of their base damage (for example, if I have a firearm and a blunt weapon with the same attack value, will the firearm inflict more health damage)?

It seems like the more Force a weapon has, the more damage it does to Stamina.  I'm not sure how firearms stack up, though.

Comment: Zombies WILL take more damage if they have less stamina if you have specced into a skill that allows it. For example, Sam B. has a passive skill that will allow you to do more damage if the enemy has less than half stamina.

Comment: You're exactly correct with force correlating with stamina damage. That and force knocks zombies back further.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, force is added to a weapons damage when striking a zombie that is fallen, so if you have a blunt weapon that has a large amount of force you can use it to usually one-shot a zombie that you have somehow knocked to the ground. (ie: kick the zombie to knock it to the ground, and finish it off with a mace to the skull)